# how to retrieve the attribute "unicodePwd" in Active Directory through java programming

Tags: java, active-directory, utf-16le

First of all, I apology for my bad english. I'm brazilian, so if there is any mistakes at the text, please, just disconsidered.

I read a lot of articles here about retrieving the attribute "unicodePwd" in Active Directory, but none of then actually helped me out.

Well, why do I need that information? I'll explain:

I have here some java routines that unify user information from differents systems one to another.
This routines get the information needed in a main Oracle Database and set the information in another Databases (Oracle and MySQL, basically).

For example: We have a private cloud system, that runs in a CentOS Linux OS, that has it own MySQL Database. To unify the users informations, including the users passwords, we get the information from the main Oracle Database and set do this system's MySQL Database, to unify user details and login information.

All the routines that i have here are working and there's no problems, but now we have a new challenge.

We need to do the same unification with ours Active Directory users, getting the information needed in this main Oracle Database and then setting all the information into Active Directory users, including the users passwords.

I already updated the password succesfully in Active Directory users, but I don't want that the password get updated everytime that this java routine runs, but only when the password changes in the main Oracle Database.

Example: When one of the users change the password in the main Oracle Database, the java routine gets this user information to set then in the same user in Active Directory. To do that properly, the routine gets the same information in Active Diretory, then it compares both passwords (Oracle's password and Active Diretory's password) and finally, if the password is different, the routine will update it, but if the password is not different, the routine will do nothing.

That is why i need to retrieve the attribute "unicodePwd" in Active Directory.

Here is some of my code:

```
import java.util.Hashtable;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.NamingEnumeration;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.naming.directory.*;
import org.apache.commons.mail.EmailException;
import javax.naming.ldap.InitialLdapContext;
import javax.naming.ldap.LdapContext;

public class ldapQuery {        

    String distinguishedName = "";
    String department = "";
    String physicalDeliveryOfficeName = "";
    String telephoneNumber = "";
    String mobile = "";
    String title = "";
    String sAMAccountName = "";
    String unicodePwd = "";

    public ldapQuery(String mail) {

        try {
            final Hashtable<String, String> env = new Hashtable<String, String>();
            final String adminName = "CN=MY DOMAIN ADMIN,CN=MY DOMAIN ADMIN FOLDER LOCALIZATION,DC=MY DOMAIN,DC=MY DOMAIN,DC=MY DOMAIN";
            final String adminPasswd = "MY DOMAIN ADMIN PASSWORD";
            final String ldapUrl = "ldaps://MY ACTIVE DIRECTORY SERVER:636";
            final String factory = "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory";
            final String authType = "simple";
            final String protocol = "ssl";
            env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, factory);
            env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, authType);
            env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, adminName);
            env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, adminPasswd); 
            env.put(Context.SECURITY_PROTOCOL, protocol);
            env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, ldapUrl);     
            DirContext ctx = new InitialLdapContext (env,null);

            SearchControls searchCtls = new SearchControls();
            String returnedAtts[] = {"sAMAccountName", "distinguishedName","department", "physicalDeliveryOfficeName", "telephoneNumber", "mobile", "title", "unicodePwd"};
            searchCtls.setReturningAttributes(returnedAtts);
            searchCtls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);
            String searchFilter = "(&(objectClass=user)(mail=" + mail +"))";
            String searchBase = "DC=MY DOMAIN,DC=MY DOMAIN,DC=MY DOMAIN";
            int totalResults = 0;
            NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> answer =ctx.search(searchBase, searchFilter, searchCtls);

            while (answer.hasMoreElements()) {
                SearchResult sr = (SearchResult)answer.next();
                totalResults++; 
                Attributes attrs = sr.getAttributes();

                if (attrs != null) {

                    distinguishedName = (String) attrs.get("distinguishedName").get();
                    department = (String) attrs.get("department").get();
                    physicalDeliveryOfficeName = (String) attrs.get("physicalDeliveryOfficeName").get();
                    telephoneNumber = (String) attrs.get("telephoneNumber").get();
                    mobile = (String) attrs.get("mobile").get();
                    title = (String) attrs.get("title").get();
                    sAMAccountName = (String) attrs.get("sAMAccountName").get();

                    Attribute passwd = attrs.get("unicodePwd");
                    unicodePwd = unicodePwd + passwd;

                    if (department == null) {
                        department = "";
                    }

                    if (physicalDeliveryOfficeName == null) {
                        physicalDeliveryOfficeName = "";
                    }

                    if (telephoneNumber == null) {
                        telephoneNumber = "";
                    }

                    if (mobile == null) {
                        mobile = "";
                    }

                    if (title == null) {
                        title = "";
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        catch (NamingException e){
            System.err.println("FAIL MESSAGE: " + e);
        }
    }

    public String ldapSearchResultDistinguishedName() {
        return distinguishedName;
    }

    public String ldapSearchResultDepartment() {
        return department;
    }

    public String ldapSearchResultPhysicalDeliveryOfficeName() {
        return physicalDeliveryOfficeName;
    }

    public String ldapSearchResultTelephoneNumber() {
        return telephoneNumber;
    }

    public String ldapSearchResultMobile() {
        return mobile;
    }

    public String ldapSearchResultTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public String ldapSearchResultUnicodePwd() {
        return unicodePwd;
    }

    public String ldapSearchResultSAMAccountName() {
        return sAMAccountName;
    }
}
```

After running the code, all the variables return the correct information but the variable "unicodePwd", that returns "null", even though the user has a password.

I know about the byte UTF-16LE thing and that the "unicodePwd" field in Active Directory is encrypted, but, as I explained earlier, i need that information decrypted in a String variable.

Any ideias?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but I stumbled across it as I was also looking for an answer to the same question. I found the answer and thought it might help anybody else who lands here.

According to [Microsoft Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc223248.aspx) it would appear that the unicodePwd attribute is NEVER returned by an LDAP search.

In my case, I need to validate that the credentials received are correct. So my plan is to use the username/password received and create a custom LdapContextFactory on the fly with those credentials. If I can contact the server successfully by doing an LdapContextFactory.get and get back an LdapContext then I can be certain that the password supplied was correct. If you don't get it back then you know it's wrong and can take it from there.